# Why can't I access a global variable from AsyncTask?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

I was trying something and stumbled upon a problem where I can't access a global variable `str1` from a class `MyAsyncTask`. I'm guessing, its got to be some declaration error but I'm not too sure as to as to what is being violated.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var str1 = "0"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        for (i in 0..5){
            val myAsyncTask = MyAsyncTask(this@MainActivity)
            myAsyncTask.execute("-")
            str1 = str1 + "1"
        }

    }
    class MyAsyncTask(private var c : Context):AsyncTask<String,Void,String>(){

        override fun doInBackground(vararg str: String?): String {
            str1 = str1 + str[0] + "2" // str1 is bolded in red, somehow, i cant access it
            return str1
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            Toast.makeText(c, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a general rule, if you have something in Kotlin that, with a similar syntax, would work in Java, decompile the Kotlin code. In IntelliJ/Android Studio, Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin bytecode. With a slight edit so the code compiles, you'll see the declaration for the class is `public static final class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask`. If you're familiar with how inner classes work, you'll know that static inner classes are like declaring them in a separate file; they do not have context related to their outer class, and can therefore not access non-static variables. It's kinda like accessing a non-static variable from a companion object or a static method. Static anything isn't attached to a specific instance of an object, and can therefore not access non-static variables.

That is the problem. If you google what you want from here, you can usually find links to documentation, at least for basic language-related stuff.

Kotlin has a special keyword you have to use if you want regular inner classes. The keyword is pretty straight-forward too: it's [`inner`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html). Change your class declaration to `inner class MyAsyncTask`, decompile, and see how it changed to `public final class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask`.

**TL;DR:**

This in Java:

```
public class MyClass {
    public class Something {}
}
```

Is this in Kotlin:

```
class MyClass {
    inner class Something 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the member of outer class you must have to use **inner** class in kotlin unlike JAVA.

here is the referecne https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#inner-classes

So your code should be like ...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var str1 = "0"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //.....
    }

    inner class MyAsyncTask(private var c : Context):AsyncTask<String,Void,String>(){

        override fun doInBackground(vararg str: String?): String {
            str1 = str1 + str[0] + "2" // str1 is bolded in red, somehow, i cant access it
            return str1
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            Toast.makeText(c, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```